# The Banach–Mazur distance for finite-dimensional $\ell_p$

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $\ell_p$ denote the usual infinite-dimensional sequence space, and if $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ then we let $\ell_p^n$ denote its $n$-dimensional counterpart.

**Conjecture.**  Let $1\leq p<\infty$.  There exists a positive real constant $C_p\in[1,\infty)$, depending only on $p$, such that for every positive integer $n\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ there is another positiver integer $k(n)\in\mathbb{Z}^+$ with the property that if $F\subseteq\ell_p$ is any $k(n)$-dimensional subspace of $\ell_p$ then there is an embedding (a linear map invertible on its range) $U:\ell_p^n\to F$ with $\|U\|\|U^{-1}\|\leq C_p$ (in other words, $F$ contains an $n$-dimensional subspace with Banach-Mazur distance $\leq C_p$ from $\ell_p^n$).

This is almost certainly known already, in which case I seek a reference.  Dvoretzky's Theorem gives an affirmative answer when $p=2$.  I am particularly interested in the case $p=1$.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound right to me. Note that for $p\in [1,2)$ the space $\ell_p$ contains almost isometric copies of $\ell_2^n$ for all $n$. Indeed, take the linear span of a sequence of zero-mean and zero-variance Gaussians in $L_p$ which is isometric to $\ell_2$ and use that that $L_p$ is finitely-representable in $\ell_p$.

Thus, taking for $F$ almost isometric copies of $\ell_2^n$ you cannot expect to find $\ell_p^{k(n)}$ in it unless $p=2$.

(Of course, as [Theo](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/29980/theo) pointed out, this extends to all Banach spaces by the Dvoretzky theorem.)

Comment: Yes, the conjecture is false for $p\neq 2$. By the way, by Dvoretzky, any  infinite dimensional $X$ contains, for every $n$, almost isometric copies of $l_2^n$.

Comment: @Theo yes, I just wanted to say politely that this is false and avoid Dvoretzky giving a more direct argument. :-)

Comment: Oh, okay, so it is. Thanks guys!

Comment: Hmm.  I guess I'm not sure why $\ell_p^n$ could not always $C$-embed in $\ell_2^{k_n}$ for sufficiently large $k_n$.  Perhaps it violates some finite representable transitivity.  But never mind.  If it is false then that is that.

Comment: @BenWallis If I am not mistaken, the reason is that, regardless how large $k_n$ is, an $n$-dimensional subspace is going to be isometric with $l_2^n$, and the Banach-Mazur distance between $l_2^n$ and $l_p^n$ goes to $\infty$ when $p\neq 2$. Thus, you cannot find a bound that depends on $p$ alone.

Comment: OH, I see.  I didn't know that every $n$-dimensional subspace of $\ell_2^k$ is isometric to $\ell_2^n$.  I guess I do now!

Comment: Simply use the fact that if a norm satisfies the Jordan-von Neumann criterion then it also satisfies this condition when restricted to a smaller subspace.